# multiple string replace of post's content for large data

Tags: plugins, search, customization, csv

I am trying to replace all player name  mentioned  into my post's content with related player's profile link.
And all the player name and player links saved in a csv file.
Example:

```
player one,www.example.com
player two,www.example.com
player three,www.example.com
player four,www.example.com
player five,www.example.com
....
upto 3000 entry
```

I have used this code

```
function link_words( $text ) {
    $replace = array(
    'player one' => '<a href="http://www.example.com">player one</a>',
    'player two' => '<a href="http://www.example.com">player two</a>',
    'player three' => '<a href="http://www.example.com">player three</a>'

    .......

    upto 3000 entry
    );
    $text = str_replace( array_keys($replace), $replace, $text );
    return $text;

}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'link_words' );
```

But this code break the site.
Can any one help on this issue?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it "breaks the site"? What is the error message? If no error is displayed, what if you switch on 'WP_DEBUG'?

Comment: H,There is a time out issue. Because of long array size.

Comment: Makes sense. Maybe instead of filtering the_content on the fly, you could actually apply these changes once and for all to the content (either directly in the DB, or with wp_update_post() ). This could be done in smaller chunks (i.e. replace a couple hundreds strings in all posts at a time instead of all 3000) to avoid timeout and/or memory exhaustion.

Comment: Hi, 'iceable' can you share some example code ?